# How to read and save start color of a Particle System in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system, particles

Lets say that I have a Particle system with start color as random between two colors say black and white. Now I know that the colors can be changed using MinMaxGradient. But how do I save the original start colors so I can use them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [ParticleSystem.MainModule.startColor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule-startColor.html).

This will return a **MinMaxGradient** which has a **colorMin** property. This is what you should save in a class field for future reuse. For example, if you initialize your ParticleSystem in the Start method:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //declare class fields for your particle system and start color
    private ParticleSystem myParticleSystem;
    private Color particleStartColor;

    void Start()
    {
        //...
        myParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient myMinMaxGradient = myParticleSystem.main.startColor;
        particleStartColor = myMinMaxGradient.colorMin;
        //...  
    }
}
```